# How to read the property of the nested object React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Please help me to get the property of the embedded object React redux:

```
{
  "id":1
  "name":"Jonh"
  "pets": {
    "namepets": {
      "String":"King-kong"
      "Valid": true
    },
    "age": {
      "String":"11",
      "Valid": true
    }
  }
}
```

If i write `console.log(this.props.user.pets)`, I see this object in my console, but I write `console.log(this.props.user.pets.namepets)`.

I have this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'namepets' of undefined

How do I get this value?

Comment: There's no explanation if console.log occurs in same place. If it's really undefined, `console.log(this.props.user.pets)` cannot output an object. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this object:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Jonh","pets":{"namepets": {"String":"King-kong","Valid": true}, "age": {"String":"11","Valid": true}}}
```

After checking `this.props.user.pets`, then the full property of this would be:

```
this.props.user.pets.namepets.pets.namepets
```

(Not very pretty is it)

Comment: `console.log(this.props)` and post the result. Post ANY `console.log()`'s that have been outputted. (Even if there is multiple)